# Can't receive email on Amazon SES service

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am developing the application that receives emails from the different users and processes them in some way.

For this purpose, I started to use [Amazon SES service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/). According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html), I verified my domain (set up MX record, added email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com and so on). Also, I set up the rule for processing received an email (it is lambda function). I didn't add any IP Address Filter so it has to receive emails from all sources.

Now, I trying to send the email to a random address on my domain (for example, admin@mydomain.com) from my Gmail account. But my message isn't delivered and response from the remote server is ***530 Authentication required*.**

I googled my error and saw only issues related to sending emails.

What have I missed with receiving email on AWS SES?

**EDIT:**[image]
This how my records look. Name fields are mostly empty because system skip my domain name (for example: change _AMAZONSES.mydomain.ext to _AMAZONSES).

Comment: You get the 530 error in an email that comes back to you? Can you show that to us, please?

Comment: The 530 Authentication required problem looks like you are not passing your SMTP credentials through to your endpoint properly.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @RredCat, I am also trying similar implementations to receive emails through SES. Can you share a bit more details related to the configurations you have made to read emails through SES

Comment: @RredCat. Why did you create the aws-ses tag for this question when there is already an amazon-ses tag (which you used)? Is AWS ses different to amazon-ses in some way?

Comment: @PaulG I am associating Amazon as e-commerce and cloud computing company. AWS (Amazon Web Services) is the separate product. So I checked for aws-* first. Also, I am going to request synonym when it is possible.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Yes, as I remember, the issue had nothing to things that I described and was fixed pretty simple.

Comment: @RredCat can you please share your solution, I am facing issues while receiving emails. I only receive a setup confirmation email in s3 bucket but no emails sent via my gmail account.

Comment: @AbdulFatah It was 5 years ago, I don't remember exactly what caused it. I guess, I missed something in the documentation. It is possible, that I sent via SNS notification about email and read the body of this email from s3

Comment: @RredCat alright, by the way I also solved my issue. I was using the incorrect inbound url that I got from some site